# How to check stored procedure is work and done without any errors?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I created a stored procedure with a Laravel and SQL server. When I created a stored procedure it works, but it doesn't use validation to check if the stored procedure is correct when choosing a table and drop function. so I want to add some validation to check if the stored procedure is correct.

**I used this code for creating store procedure from laravel to SQL server:**

```
DB::statement(DB::raw("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ".$data['name_procedure']));
DB::statement(DB::raw($data['store_procedure']));
```

**I tried using try and catch to check for validation:**

```
try{   
}
catch(Exception $e) {
}
```

**For execute I used:**

```
DB::select(name_store_procedure)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your post has no information about what you are trying to do. What do you mean by if the stored procedure is correct? Or do you mean you want to capture and handle errors? What do you want to happen if there is an error? You put that logic inside the catch. The try block contains the code where you want to capture the errors if they occur.

Comment: sorry about that, I mean I want to capture and handle the error, and if there's is an error I  want to remove the stored procedure from sql server.

Comment: Huh??? Is this when you create the procedure?

Comment: hmm, the point is if i got errors in stored procedure i want to automatically delete current stored procedure

Comment: If there is ever an error during the execution of a procedure you want to drop it from the database? Or if the error you are referring to is when it is being created you don't have to do anything. It would be unable to create it so there is no procedure to drop.

Comment: if I got error during the execution of a procedure I want to drop it from the database

Comment: That sounds like a really really bad strategy. But whatever, this is your system. Put logic in the catch to drop the procedure. You do realize this is like deleting a method from your code when an error happens right?

Comment: yup, thanks for your advice